# Looking for an old story about undercover reporter in pvc latex tech suit

Tags: story-identification

I came across this story online probably between 10-12 years ago. A reporter goes undercover to “jail” but instead of jail, the prisoners are put into high-tech pvc/latex suits and outcasted among society. The suits become sentient and self aware. The reporter’s suit is named “Winter”. I don’t remember the author’s name of this story but it had “Dolly” in her name….so something like GothicDolly or DeviantDolly…something along those lines.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is *[Eudeamon](http://www.evil-dolly.com/assets/eudeamon.pdf)* by Evil Dolly. The main character is an investigative reporter who interviews a 'Bane' wearing a 'Banesuit' described thusly;

> She was entirely coated with high-gloss, black latex from head to toe.
> The suit left nothing to the imagination while simultaneously
> revealing nothing.  It was more than merely skin-tight; there were no
> seams, zippers, or openings of any kind.  There were no folds or
> stress lines that would identify it as a normal latex garment or any
> other type of clothing.  It appeared to be more like a second skin
> than an outfit, as though it had been painted directly onto her body.

The suit is sentient and names itself Winter.

> : *Katrina!  I know my name now.  My name is Winter! :*
> “W-winter?” Katrina asked, barely able to speak. “Why that name?”
> : *Because I love the images it makes in your mind when you think it :*

Self-published on their [own site](http://www.evil-dolly.com/assets/eudeamon.pdf).